# Errors running Batch files

Tags: windows-server-2003, batch-file

I have recently constructed a batch file on my server to zip up data and send it to a backup source for archiving. However when I run the batch file I get the following error...

'7z.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Any suggestions on why I am getting this message and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the path to 7z.exe in the front portion of your batch file or call it through its full directory path and executable (two quick and easy options in correcting the situation).

Comment: I found out it is even simpler than that. For some reason my windows 2003 server does not have Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools. Therefore I don't "functionally" have the ability to zip up my files using a batch file.

Comment: ??? 7z.exe does not appear to be part of the Resource Kit based on the following Microsoft link: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&DisplayLang=en.

Comment: @Cpt. Jack, the resource kit plays absolutely no part in this. As for the "some reason", have you considered that it's because it's not part of the default installation?

Comment: Yes you are correct, it appears as though 7z.exe is not apart of the resource toolkit. I was actually looking at installing that because my server lacks Robocopy, which is within the toolkit. That is what sparked my interest within this download. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No problem... It did have the head scratching for a little bit.